# Google API for Google Services

Tags: google-api

Normally I can find just about anything using a serach engine. But this time I seemed to have failed

I wanted to know if it is possible to get a list of services that are enabled and disabled such as GMail, Google+, YouTube, ect. I know I can do this through the Services tab on the Organizations and Users page. However I want to create an application that will allow me to enable and disable services from the app and not have to login to a webpage.

I have been poking around in the google apis and the only one that I found that is almost there is the discovery api but it does not list the core google services and there isn't a way to enable or disable the services.

Basically I just want to know, is there a way to do this and maybe where to look.

Comment: r u looking for this: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs?

Comment: Thanks but i looked though all of those and didn't see a way to do what i want. Other then to retrieve some of the google services that are available using the discovery api