# A Google API to know which services are enabled?

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I'm looking for a Google API call to know which services (Gmail in my case) are enabled for an organization or for a user.

The question has been asked without answer there : [Google API for Google Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033005/google-api-for-google-services)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating draft via Google Gmail API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493213/creating-draft-via-google-gmail-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this existed, it would likely be in the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) rather than the Gmail API. That being said, I've never seen this and wasn't able to find any hint of it within the specific APIs within the SDK (would likely be in the [Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/)).

I am pretty sure this isn't possible via API currently.

Comment: Sad, because if the Gmail service is deactivated, the mailboxes content is not deleted for 30 days and is available via the API, even if the web interface is not accessible!!!